# Do I need to make the Infiltration Tools myself?

Tags: achievements, persona-5

After reaching a certain Confidant rank with the Temperance Confidant, you can have them make Infiltration Tools for you, among other things.

Does having this person make Infiltration Tools for you count towards the Craftworker trophy? The description for this trophy is simply "Create all types of infiltration tools", so it doesn't seem to specify whether it has to be *you* making them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to make them yourself. You cannot have you Confidant make them for you. From [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835628-persona-5/75277241):

> You need to make them yourself.

And from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Persona5/comments/64q4vt/heads_up_regarding_craftworker/):

> Alll tools made by her do not count towards the trophy.

Another post in that thread even adds that making tools in does not count towards this trophy:

> Just a heads up if you make something in class then it won't count towards the trophy either. At least not in the JP version.

Thus, it looks like in order to get the Craftworker trophy, you have to make all of the Infiltration Tools yourself, at your desk at Leblanc.